# google-test: code coverage

Tags: c++, code-coverage, googletest

Is it possible to get code coverage done by tests using google test framework?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, I've successfully used both free (gcov) and commercial (CTC++) tools. No special steps are needed, just follow the documentation.

More details can be found in this blog
http://googletesting.blogspot.dk/2014/07/measuring-coverage-at-google.html

Comment: Don't forget that Lcov is a nice GUI for Gcov - http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php  and take a look also at http://ggcov.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: The link does not explain how to integrate gcov with gtest.

Comment: I do not see the implementation.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, You can club your Gtest Based application with support of Gcov/lcov.
refer the documentation of lcov http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php

there is one linux test project utility available which does your job very easy and is very self-interpretative.

`lcov` - a graphical GCOV front-end

Download from Ubuntu repo:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lcov
```

1. Use following commands in your build directory

   ```
   $ lcov --directory ./build/ --capture --output-file ./code_coverage.info -rc lcov_branch_coverage=1
   ```
2. Run the Application
3. Generate HTML Report

   ```
   $ genhtml code_coverage.info --branch-coverage --output-directory ./code_coverage_report/
   ```

This will look something like - http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/output/index.html

Comment: As an addition to your answer:
Using CMake, I had to add the following lines to CMakeLists.txt to get the right compiler and linker flags when building the tests:

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lgcov")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")
(Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797272)

Then, the tests had to be run once before executing lcov to get the correct results.

Answer (score 17):

(Only works on Windows)

It seems this question is still active, so here's an additional option. I've just tested Google Tests on our code coverage solution (yes, I'm the author), which works on Visual Studio. The project can be found at: https://github.com/atlaste/CPPCoverage

Instructions: right-click project, run coverage. :-)

If you prefer an XML output (for CI), you can call the coverage executable manually.

Comment: @kevr How exactly? Let me spell it out: "Is it possible to get code coverage done by tests using google test framework?" -- yes you can, if you're using this tool, and if you are happy with the [VS/Windows] constraints of the tool. I'd say it's spot on.

Comment: It's off topic. He was asking generically, not about Visual Studio on Windows. An answer to the generic question should be one with an answer that can apply generically.

Comment: @kevr If that's your definition, then my answer here is just as much off-topic as all the other answers here. I mean come on, one of them actually has a "download from ubuntu repo" in the answer - how is that any more generic or on-topic than my answer? Fact is that my answer provides exactly what the OP is asking with just one installation and two clicks.