# How do I add a linker or compile flag in a CMake file?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using the `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` compiler. When I try to compile a simple "Hello, World!" program it compiles fine. When I test it by adding a simple exception handling in that code it works too (after adding `-fexceptions` .. I guess it is disabled by default).

This is for an Android device, and I only want to use CMake, not `ndk-build`.

For example - `first.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   try
   {
   }
   catch (...)
   {
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`./arm-linux-androideadi-g++ -o first-test first.cpp -fexceptions`

It works with no problem...

**The problem** ... I am trying to compile the file with a CMake file.

I want to add the `-fexceptions` as a flag. I tried with

```
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -fexceptions ) or set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "fexceptions" )
```

and

```
set ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "fexceptions")
```

It still displays an error.

Comment: right now I'm having the same problem, and I'm trying different things. Hang a little and I post an answer. For compile flags, there is an unclean but easy way : add_definitions("-truc")

Comment: For a more up-to-date discussion on this question (especially if you are using CMake 3.x or newer): [What is the modern method for setting general compile flags in CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake/23995391#23995391).

Comment: If the link flags you want aim at configuring **rpath** then have a look at the specific CMake rpath commands https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77829529/14055985

Answer (score 303, accepted):

---

**Please be aware that due to the evolution of CMake since the writing of this answer in 2012, the majority of the recommendations provided here are now obsolete or no longer recommended, with improved alternatives available.**

---

Suppose you want to add those flags (better to declare them in a constant):

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lgcov")
```

There are several ways to add them:

1. The easiest one (not clean, but easy and convenient, and works only for compiler flags, C & C++ at once):

   ```
   add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})
   ```
2. Appending to corresponding CMake variables:

   ```
   SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
   SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")
   ```
3. Using target properties, cf. doc [CMake compile flag target property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_FLAGS) and need to know the target name.

   ```
   get_target_property(TEMP ${THE_TARGET} COMPILE_FLAGS)
   if(TEMP STREQUAL "TEMP-NOTFOUND")
       SET(TEMP "") # Set to empty string
   else()
       SET(TEMP "${TEMP} ") # A space to cleanly separate from existing content
   endif()
   # Append our values
   SET(TEMP "${TEMP}${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
   set_target_properties(${THE_TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${TEMP} )
   ```

Right now I use method 2.

Comment: why is add_definitions() unclean?

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC: The [official documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) says: _This command can be used to add any flags, but it is intended to add preprocessor definitions_. I think that's why.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer this really show very old style CMAKE, refer to the answer by @vitaut for how any new CMAKE code should be structured with regard to compile time parameters

Comment: `string(APPEND CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "new_value")` is shorter and cleaner than `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} new_value")`

Comment: outdated advice

Answer (score 252):

In newer versions of CMake you can set compiler and linker flags for a single target with [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) and [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) respectively (yes, the latter sets linker options too):

```
target_compile_options(first-test PRIVATE -fexceptions)
```

The advantage of this method is that you can control propagation of options to other targets that depend on this one via `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE`.

As of CMake 3.13 you can also use [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_link_options.html) to add linker options which makes the intent clearer.

Comment: I've tried to use it: `target_compile_options(main_static PRIVATE --static)` but it doesn't seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: `-static` is probably a linker, not compiler option. Try passing it to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Oh, `target_link_libraries` I've missed that part of doc: "Specify libraries **or flags** to use when linking a given target.". Thanks.

Comment: A recent addition: CMake 3.13 introduces [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html#command:target_link_options) as a cleaner way to specify linker flags. You should avoid using `target_link_libraries` for linker flags in the future and use `target_link_options` instead.

Comment: There is also [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_compile_options.html) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501481/difference-between-add-compile-options-and-setcmake-cxx-flags
and more recently [add_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_link_options.html)

Comment: how do you specify multiple linker options?

Comment: @m4l490n you pass multiple arguments to `target_link_options`.

Comment: @BruceAdams But please, never use them in modern target-based CMake.

Comment: @val I agree, but qualified with an almost. There are some valid uses for global project settings where cmake doens't have them yet. So not for enabling C++11 but maybe for enabling certain sanitisers when debugging.

Comment: While this is better than the accepted answer, it is still missing a generator expression to prevent that flag from being added to an incompatible compiler. But since this flag is only meant to be used in a specific compiler, it should be added to a tool chain file in the variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT

Comment: @AlexReinking I wrote an answer involving toolchains. I wasn't aware of the `_INIT` variants however. Thanks

Comment: You should really not advise OP to use linker-specific flags without ensuring the linker  to be used actually accepts them, or alternatively using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to only add the flag for relevant linkers.

Answer (score 59):

Try setting the variable [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) instead of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fexceptions")
```

The variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` only affects the C compiler, but you are compiling C++ code.

Adding the flag to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is redundant.

Comment: i tried that but it still gives error.   Is  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fexceptions") the only way to specify compiler flag.

Comment: i solved the problem but not in a good way its a poor workaround .. i made -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= "-fexceptions" in the command line. for some reason cmake is not reading flags from the .cmake file. :(  .. thank you sakra for your answer ..

Comment: -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= "-fexceptions"

There should NOT be a space between the = and "

Comment: Regarding what you said: "for some reason cmake is not reading flags from the .cmake file." Make sure you clear up the existing cache. This can be done by deleting everything from the build directory before cmake again.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: My general advice is to avoid adding compiler flags explicitly via CMake altogether. Toolchain files are for configuring novel toolchains, not customising an existing GCC toolchain. A project's CMake is more clean, portable, and future-proof when it is toolchain-agnostic. Separate the concern of describing how your artefacts are constituted (using CMake) from the concern of customising compiler flags. I find environment variables, such as [CXXFLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html) are much better at maintaining this separation of concerns. However, in answer to the OP...

The preferred way to specify toolchain-specific options is using CMake's [toolchain facility](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). This ensures that there is a clean division between:

- instructions on how to organise source files into targets -- expressed in *CMakeLists.txt* files, entirely toolchain-agnostic; and
- details of how certain toolchains should be configured -- separated into CMake script files, extensible by future users of your project, scalable.

Ideally, there should be no compiler/linker flags in your *CMakeLists.txt* files -- even within `if`/`endif` blocks. And your program should build for the native platform with the default toolchain (e.g. GCC on GNU/Linux or MSVC on Windows) without any additional flags.

Steps to add a toolchain:

1. Create a file, e.g. *arm-linux-androideadi-gcc.cmake* with global toolchain settings:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-fexceptions")
   ```

   (You can find an example Linux cross-compiling toolchain file [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux).)
2. When you want to generate a build system with this toolchain, specify the [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html) parameter on the command line:

   ```bash
   mkdir android-arm-build && cd android-arm-build
   cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$(pwd)/../arm-linux-androideadi-gcc.cmake ..
   ```

   (Note: you cannot use a relative path.)
3. Build as normal:

   ```bash
   cmake --build .
   ```

Toolchain files make cross-compilation easier, but they have other uses:

- Hardened diagnostics for your unit tests.

  ```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")
  ```
- Tricky-to-configure development tools.

  ```
  # toolchain file for use with gcov
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "--coverage -fno-exceptions -g")
  ```
- Enhanced safety checks.

  ```
  # toolchain file for use with gdb
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-fsanitize=address,undefined -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fsanitize=address,undefined -static-libasan")
  ```

Comment: See docs for [CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG_INIT.html) and [CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_INIT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html)

Comment: In general, in CMake, the variables `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS[_<CONFIG>]` are meant to be set by the client building your app/library. They should never be programatically set. Appended to, rarely.

Comment: @AlexReinking updated, plus `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`.

Comment: This was the answer, after much searching thank you @JohnMcFarlane !

Comment: @AlexReinking passing `-DCMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` to `cmake` appears to override `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_INIT`. For this reason, I'm tempted to use a custom flag and set it explicitly in _CMakeLists.txt_.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add linker flags to a specific target using the `LINK_FLAGS` property:

```
set_property(TARGET ${target} APPEND_STRING PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS " ${flag}")
```

If you want to propagate this change to other targets, you can create a dummy target to link to.

Answer (score 4):

Since **CMake 3.13** there is the [**`add_link_options`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html) command.

It applies to all subsequent `add_library` and `add_executable` commands in the same scope and sub-scopes.

This can be useful for project-wide settings. For example:

```
add_link_options("-fexceptions")

add_executable(first-test first.cpp)
```

For specific targets there is [**`target_link_options`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html#command:target_link_options):

```
add_executable(first-test first.cpp)

target_link_options(first-test PUBLIC "-fexceptions")
```

`PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE` as usual determines how the option is propagated to downstream dependencies.

There's also a `BEFORE` flag for cases when the option needs to be prepended instead of appended.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I needed a precompile definition named "NO_DEBUG":

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -DNO_DEBUG")
```

Then from code

```
#ifdef NO_DEBUG
.....
```

Comment: That's what add_definitions is for.

Comment: Prefer using `add_compile_options("-std=c++14")` and `add_compile_definitions("NO_DEBUG")`

Answer (score -1):

With CMake 3.4+, `APPEND` can be used with the `string` command to add flags.

```
string(APPEND CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " -fexceptions")
```