# cmake list append for compiler flags yields bogus results?

Tags: cmake

I need to add various flags to my C and C++ compile lines in my CMake files (CMake 2.8.10.2).  I see some people use `add_definitions` but from what I can see that is intended for preprocessor flags (`-D`).  I have some flags that I don't want passed to the preprocessor.

So I've been trying to modify `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.  I see that some people were using something like:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -new -flags -here")
```

but then I read in the cmake docs that this is less efficient, and the right way to do it is to use `list(APPEND ...)`, like this:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS -new -flags -here)
```

However, when I do this my compile line contains the flags separated by semicolons and is a syntax error.  I read that this is now lists are stored internally, but I figured this would be taken care of by cmake when I used the variable.  This seems so basic; am I doing something wrong?  I mean, what the heck good are these lists if they can't be used unless you happen to want a semicolon-separated list of values (and who wants that, other than I guess Windows %PATH% settings or something)?  Should I be using the quoted version even though the docs suggest it's less efficient/appropriate?

Comment: I use a macro for the set() approach though as it's easy to get a mismatch in the var names when copying things etc:

macro(append name item)
 set(${name} "${${name}} ${item}")
endmacro()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you would indeed normally use the `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -new -flags -here")` technique.

You're right in that in most other contexts CMake can "translate" a semi-colon separated list into something meaningful for the compiler (e.g. the list of source files in an executable), but in this case, CMake takes the flags as a single, complete string to pass to the compiler/linker.

You could if you really wanted keep the list of flags as a CMake list, but then before exiting the CMakeLists.txt, you could yourself "translate" the list into a single string value of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, but it's unusual to see this.

Comment: A more concise idiom is `string(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS " -new-flags").

Answer (score 29):

In CMake, a "list" is a string of items separated by **semi-colons**. For example:

```
set(FOO "a")
list(APPEND FOO "b") # now FOO="a;b"
list(APPEND FOO "c") # now FOO="a;b;c"
```

In CMake, a string of **space**-seperated items is just a string, not a list. Use the `string(APPEND)` command to append to it. For example:

```
set(FOO "a")
string(APPEND FOO " b") # now FOO="a b"
string(APPEND FOO " c") # now FOO="a b c"
```

On old versions of CMake that lack the `string(APPEND)` command, you should fallback to the `set` command. For example:

```
set(FOO "a")
set(FOO "${FOO} b")
set(FOO "${FOO} c")
```

Comment: By the logic you just explained, `set(FOO "${FOO} b")` would add `" b"` to the existing last item (i.e. `"x;y;z"` would become `"x;y;z b"`). You would need to quote the arguments separately: `set(FOO "${FOO}" "b")`. For compiler flags this isn't a big deal because those separate arguments are going to be joined with spaces before being passed to the compiler anyway, but it's still best avoided. Of course, you avoid this problem by using `list(APPEND ...)` as you said, but even then you need to be careful to quote arguments separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing recently when using the modern `target_compile_options` command, which appears to (only?) take a list:

```
list(APPEND MY_C_FLAGS "-Wall")
list(APPEND MY_C_FLAGS "-Werror")

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MY_C_FLAGS})
```

I am by no means a cmake expert, so correct me if this is somehow inappropriate.  In any event, it prevented quoting the CFLAGs on the gcc cmdline.