# What is the modern method for setting general compile flags in CMake?

Tags: cmake

There are multiple mechanisms offered by CMake for getting flags to the compiler:

- [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` variables](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LANG_FLAGS)
- [`add_compile_options` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_compile_options)
- [`set_target_properties` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aset_target_properties)

Is there one method that is preferred over the other in modern use? If so why? Also, how can this method be used with multiple configuration systems such as MSVC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a linker or compile flag in a CMake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file)

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77829529/14055985

Answer (score 135, accepted):

For modern CMake (versions 2.8.12 and up) you should use [`target_compile_options`](https://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html), which uses target properties internally.

`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` is a global variable and the most error-prone to use. It also does not support [generator expressions](https://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), which can come in very handy.

`add_compile_options` is based on directory properties, which is fine in some situations, but usually not the most natural way to specify options.

`target_compile_options` works on a per-target basis (through setting the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) and [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) target properties), which usually results in the cleanest CMake code, as the compile options for a source file are determined by which project the file belongs to (rather than which directory it is placed in on the hard disk). This has the additional advantage that it [automatically takes care of passing options on](https://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements) to dependent targets if requested.

Even though they are little bit more verbose, the per-target commands allow a reasonably fine-grained control over the different build options and (in my personal experience) are the least likely to cause headaches in the long run.

In theory, you could also set the respective properties directly using `set_target_properties`, but `target_compile_options` is usually more readable.

For example, to set the compile options of a target `foo` based on the configuration using generator expressions you could write:

```
target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>")
target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS}>")
```

The `PUBLIC`, `PRIVATE`, and `INTERFACE` keywords define the [scope of the options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html). E.g., if we link `foo` into `bar` with `target_link_libraries(bar foo)`:

- `PRIVATE` options will only be applied to the target itself (`foo`) and not to other libraries (consumers) linking against it.
- `INTERFACE` options will only be applied to the consuming target `bar`
- `PUBLIC` options will be applied to both, the original target `foo` and the consuming target `bar`

Comment: Note that `target_compile_options` **add** options, so you can modify last line like [this](http://pastebin.com/jCDW5Aa9) to make it more readable)

Comment: @ComicSansMS Great answer and the best (and most up-to-date) that I could find on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: If I want to have the same strict set of compilation flags globally, what's the best modern way to do it? Specifying the same flags again and again for different targets with target_compile_options seems like a bad idea

Comment: @user3667089 The target-specific properties usually get initialized by a variable or directory property. The manpage for the respective property tells you which exactly. In the case of compile options, the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_OPTIONS) directory property does this. You can use the [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_compile_options.html#command:add_compile_options) command to set this. The options for which this is a good approach are usually few and far between.

Comment: I'm confused, if I have ---set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -ggdb -Og -Wall")--- can I change for ---set(DEBUG_FLAGS "-g3 -ggdb -Og -Wall") target_compile_options(hsm-parser PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_FLAGS}>")---

Comment: @ComicSansMS What is the use of `PUBLIC` in `target_compile_options`?

Comment: @RamanaReddy I added additional explanation of the `PUBLIC` keyword to the answer.

Comment: Note that if you're  `MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS ` contains spaces you will need the  `SHELL: ` prefix, like this:  `target_compile_options(${NAME} PUBLIC $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:SHELL:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>) `. Otherwise you will get compilation errors as Cmake will wrap your compiler options in double quotes.

Comment: Could you add an example to the answer?

Comment: But what if my target has source files in multiple languages, and I would only like to set flags for, say, Fortran, but not C++? Can I still use `target_compile_options` instead of `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`?

Comment: @knia If you absolutely do need to mix source languages and cannot break that up into separate targets, you may want to use the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS` source file property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_sf:COMPILE_OPTIONS) instead.