# Using build type in CMake 3.x

Tags: cmake

In the 2.x version of CMake, the cmake option `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` controlled options to be passed to the compiler. For example, if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` then the options passed to the compiler was `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO` for C++ and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO` for C (http://binglongx.wordpress.com/tag/cmake_build_type/).

In the new 3.x version of CMake there are commands `add_compile_options` and `target_compiler_options` for adding options to the compiler ([What is the modern method for setting general compile flags in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/)).

#### Questions

How do I define which build type CMake should use? Is it still, for example, `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`?

How do I make use of this build type in my CMakeLists.txt?

Has CMake defined all the build types, or can I define custom, additional, build types?

Has CMake set any default compiler options for each of the build types (for example `-g` for the Debug build type)?

Comment: `the cmake option CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE controlled options to be passed to the compiler` nope, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/2288008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to stick to a single question per question in the future. You might risk getting closed as *too broad* otherwise. Also, you are more likely to get good answers for well-defined, precise questions.

> How do I define which build type CMake should use? Is it still, for
>   example, `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`?

Yes, this did not change.

> How do I make use of this build type in my CMakeLists.txt?

Use [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). For example:

```
target_compile_options(my_program PUBLIC $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Werror>)
# Warnings are errors for debug build only
```

> Has CMake defined all the build types, or can I define custom,
>   additional, build types?

You can add your own type if the defaults don't cut it for you. Note though that this can be a bit fiddly, so I wouldn't do it unless you have good reasons. Take a look at [`CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES.html).

> Has CMake set any default compiler options for each of the build types
>   (for example -g for the Debug build type)?

CMake does a pretty good job at choosing the right defaults for the different configurations. In particular, Debug and RelWithDebInfo builds generate symbols correctly (`-g` on gcc) and Release builds are optimized quite well.