# Why vector.resize() on the same vector take around 4 milliseconds (JNI)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, resize, allocation

I am using JNI in my android app

I have such code

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SIZE", "SIZE ::: %s :: %s", std::to_string(vertices.size()).c_str(), std::to_string(NumVertices * 3).c_str());

vertices.resize(NumVertices * 3); 

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "AFTER ", "AFTER  ::: %s ", std::to_string(vertices.size()).c_str());
```

Here `vertices` it is `std::vector<float>` , I am reuse the same vector every call to method, so I expect that first time method resize really make memory allocation, but next time NO (Just if I try to resize to size bigger than I have currently).

But in my case before resize size of vector around 500.000 items, and resize to 90.000 items... So, there should not be any memory allocation.

In addition I checked address `&vertices[0]` before resize and after resize I get the same address - so, it is means that any memory allocation happening.

So, question is - why this line of code

```
vertices.resize(NumVertices * 3);
```

take around 4-5 milliseconds? It should take almost 0 ...

**EDIT1**

If I change my code like this

```
long vertices_size = NumVertices * 3;

if (vertices.size() == 0)
{
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "INSIDE2", "INSIDE2 ::: %s", 
 std::to_string(vertices.size()).c_str());
        vertices.resize(200000); // x y z for each vertex
}

long long int duration3 = duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - t3).count();
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "INSIDE1", "INSIDE1 ::: %s", std::to_string(duration3).c_str());
```

So, time execution came to `0,02` milliseconds, that looks right...

**EDIT2**

Compiler version

[image]

And in my `CMake` file I have such configuration (not sure about it)

[image]

**EDIT3**

Added optimization configuration to `CMake` file (according to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41361741/5709159)

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? What are your specific compiler flags (and what compiler are you using)?

Comment: Pleas provide a [mcve].

Comment: Don't forget that your print statements also take time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If I understood you correctly, so added to question ... If is it ok?

Comment: @rustyx provided... added to question

Comment: @Aleksey From what I can see in the images, you don't optimize your code. Try adding a compiler flag like `-O3`

Comment: @JVApen Added configuration. Also added to question. But it is the same behavior

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko this is not a MWE. Also, a crucial part, the definition of the vector, is missing.

Comment: @tos-1 what is MWE? Definition as usual `std::vector<int> m_myVector`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko See [mre].  The code has to be compilable on its own.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Have you tried to use a debugger or strace or other tools to try to figure out what vector.resize() actually does?