# Please explain this CMake syntax for adding compiler options to a target

Tags: cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt which builds a number of targets. Call one `foo` and one `bar`

At the moment `foo` and `bar` both share some settings given to `ccmake` configuration

```
 CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS =  -W -Wall
 CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -g -pg
```

etc

I need to add `-fPIC` to `foo` but not `bar`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake) I want to use [`TARGET_COMPILE_OTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html)

```
target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>")
target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS}>")
```

> Note that target_compile_options **add** *[sic]* options

This sounds like it's what I need but what does this syntax mean?

```
"$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>"
```

To clarify, I want to add `-fPIC` as an *additional* flag when compiling `foo` but not when compiling `bar`

Please explain the `$<$<` business and show me, concretely, how `-fPIC` would be added as a flag for `foo`.

Comment: Replace `${MY_*DEBUG_OPTIONS}` by -fPIC or PIC, not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `$<$<` falls into the generator expressions category: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7),
precisely into

> logical expressions

So in your case,

```
"$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>"
```

expands to MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS when the DEBUG configuration is used, and otherwise expands to nothing.
So in your case you should add `-fPIC` for example to `MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS`.
To be a little bit more precise:

```
$<CONFIG:DEBUG>
```

evaluates to 1 or 0 depending weather CONFIG is DEBUG or not, respectively.
Then you will have either:

```
$<0:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>
```

or

`$<1:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>`

The two expressions above will evaluate in the following way:

`$<0:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>` will evaluate to

> Empty string (ignores ${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS})

while `$<1:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>` will evaluate to

> Content of ${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}

as the documentation states.
In the last case then `-fPIC` will be added to one of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG.