# CMake: Is there a way of passing options to g++ but not to nvcc

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, cmake, nvcc

In CMakeList.txt I do want to add the `-std=g++0x` to the g++ options like this:
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x)`

However all the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are passed on to nvcc as well, via the `-Xcompiler` flag (which is done automatically). However nvcc doesn't work with the `gnu++0x` standard.

Is there a way of passing the flag to g++ but not to nvcc

The compiler is specified by

```
if(CUDA_NVCC_HOST_COMPILER)
    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "--compiler-bindir=${CUDA_NVCC_HOST_COMPILER}")
endif(CUDA_NVCC_HOST_COMPILER)
```

Comment: What CUDA version do you have? Afaik C++11 is supported since CUDA 7.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995391/1418828

Comment: @Shadow nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0

Comment: @Michael year 2013 was 4 years ago. It's an entire epoch in software development. Nvidia did not support C++11 back then. Even GCC did not support it fully. You should upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

From the [FindCUDA documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html):

```
CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS (Default ON)
-- Set to ON to propagate CMAKE_{C,CXX}_FLAGS and their configuration
   dependent counterparts (e.g. CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG) automatically to the
   host compiler through nvcc's -Xcompiler flag.  This helps make the
   generated host code match the rest of the system better.  Sometimes
   certain flags give nvcc problems, and this will help you turn the flag
   propagation off.  This does not affect the flags supplied directly to nvcc
   via CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS or through the OPTION flags specified through
   CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY, CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE, or CUDA_WRAP_SRCS.  Flags used for
   shared library compilation are not affected by this flag.
```

So, to fix your problem, just put

```
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS FALSE)
```

near the start of your CMake script.

Comment: @MultipleMonmials your answer is useful, but it didn't solve the problem. I did set the `-std` switch on a target by target basis using `target_compile_options(<target> PUBLIC -std=c++11)`