# problems linking boost with cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, linker

I would like to compile & link the following demo application using `boost::logger` but I get the following output:

```
d$ rm -rf *; cmake ..;make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Boost_LIBRARIES:
-- 
-- BOOST_INCLUDEDIR:
-- /path/to/env/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/src/tmp/logger/build
Scanning dependencies of target logger
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable logger
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `init()':
/path/to/src/tmp/logger/logger.cpp:21: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::get()'
/path/to/src/tmp/logger/logger.cpp:24: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::set_filter(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::filter const&)'
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name::attribute_name(char const*)':
/path/to/env/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_name.hpp:80: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)'
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::light_rw_mutex()':
/path/to/env/include/boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:103: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::~light_rw_mutex()':
/path/to/env/include/boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:107: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock_shared()':
/path/to/env/include/boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:111: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock_shared()':
/path/to/env/include/boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:115: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::~once_block_sentry()':
...
...
```

now my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(LOGGER)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/path/to/env/include")
set(BOOST_ROOT "/path/to/env/include")
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS on CACHE BOOL "Do not search system for Boost")


find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

message(STATUS Boost_LIBRARIES:)
message (STATUS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message(STATUS BOOST_INCLUDEDIR:)
message(STATUS ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(logger logger.cpp)
target_include_directories(logger PUBLIC ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK")
```

and `logger.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;


void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("sample.log");

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main(void) {
    init();

    std::cout <<"Hello World!";
```

As you can see in the cmake output, `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` did not return anything, I suspect this to be the culprit even though, the compiler found the boost includes at the non-standard path.

Comment: You forget to add `log` component when finding the Boost: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS log REQUIRED)`. After that, `Boost_LIBRARIES` should be empty no longer, and you need to link your executable with it. Also, `BOOST_ROOT` variable is expected to contain *installation directory* of the Boost, not its include directory "/path/to/env/include".

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your CMakeLists.

## Linking

You haven't linked your executable against Boost, so although you will have access to the declarations of Boost functions from the headers found at `${Boost_INCLUDEDIR}`, you'll see undefined references to their definitions. Hence, you need to:

```
target_link_libraries(logger PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

This will resolve the linking issue.

## Compile Definitions

Less problematically, your usage of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` has some issues. Using `set()` for `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is deprecated, but the correct usage is:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} <value>")
```

Because set() overwrites. However, the more modern way to do this would be:

```
target_compile_options(logger PRIVATE -g -Wall)
target_compile_definitions(logger PRIVATE BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK=true)
```

This will ensure that these definitions are used only for this exectuable. Note that this step will require a relatively recent version of CMake.

## Include Directories

The findBoost module exports a number of variables, one of which is `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}`. This variable represents the directories in which boost files are stored. Boost also looks for a variable, `${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}`, which is the path to the top-level directory of the boost headers. Currently, you're using the latter to represent the former, which should be corrected.

Comment: Ha, now it can't find the headers. I get: `fatal error: boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp: No such file or directory` using the "modern" way with `cmake version 3.5.2`

Comment: Does "/path/to/env/include" look something like /path/to/boost/? Might try just fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp, as the "boost" part might already be prepended. I tried compiling this on my end, but have boost installation differences that make it challenging.

Comment: @DrWatson no, it is like `/path/to/env/include/boost/`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant-- it ends in boost. So if you #include <boost/a/thing>, it will search for /path/to/env/include/boost/boost/a/thing, which is one too many boosts, I think.

Comment: I don't know, now I get `fatal error: fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp: No such file or directory` - saying this, I think it still needs boost cause `$BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` comes w/o it - hmm, anyways, that's not it....it doesn't work either way

Comment: Alright, thanks for giving it a shot. Think I've got it. From the docs, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html, findBoost exports the variable Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS, which is all of the subdirectories underneath /path/to/env/include/boost/. So you want target_include_directories(logger PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}), not target_include_directories(logger PUBLIC ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}). If that works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179607/discussion-between-dr-watson-and-cerr).

Comment: "Using `set()` for `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is deprecated" - First time hear about that. While there are CMake commands (per-target and global) which can set compiler parameters of different types, I always consider to be a good style to add parameters like `-g` and `-Wall` via `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, if you want to apply those parameters to the whole project.

Comment: There is some debate, but the general consensus is that per-target options is preferred, followed by add_compile_definitions(), if project-level flags are desired. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake/23995391