# CMake undefined reference to `pthread_create` in Github Action Ubuntu image

Tags: c++, cmake, pthreads

When I was using Github Action CI, I found that no matter what method I used to link, there was no way to link pthread_create

But this error only appears in the Ubuntu environment, Windows, macOS are no problem

I tried:

1. Not Working

   ```
   set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
   set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)

   find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

   add_executable(xxx xxx.c)
   target_link_libraries(xxx PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
   ```
2. Not Working

   ```
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
   set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pthread")
   ```

You can view the compiled log here:

https://github.com/YuzukiTsuru/lessampler/runs/6640320037?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: The output contains much more targets that the `CMakeLists.txt` which you show us. Please, prepare [mcve]: the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) and build output for it (which contains the error message). Note, that Stack Overflow **requires** error message to be in the **question post** itself, not *linked* to other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the build log carefully

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/GenerateAudioModelTest.dir/__/src/GenerateAudioModel.cpp.o: in function `GenerateAudioModel::GenerateModelFromFile()':
GenerateAudioModel.cpp:(.text+0x27aa): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

You notice the error has happened while linking the target `GenerateAudioModelTest` that is located in the directory `test` and CMakeLists.txt there does not have the compiler flags you shown. Just add `-pthread` in `test/CMakeLists.txt`.

---

This is a bad idea.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
```

Use

```
target_compile_options(GenerateAudioModelTest PRIVATE -pthread)
```

See [What is the modern method for setting general compile flags in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Not Working

You *did not* link with Thread::Thread nor any library that the target links to.

https://github.com/YuzukiTsuru/lessampler/blob/a6bb7e7d7ac30b6b4043d4f717a2d4deb7fb7638/test/CMakeLists.txt#L22

> 2. Not Working

Flags have to be set *before* `add_executable`. Which means *before* all the `add_subdirectories`. And flags have directory scope. Use `targe_compile_options`.

https://github.com/YuzukiTsuru/lessampler/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt

3. Consider just making it one library, why so many, and so many CMakeLists.txt in every directory. If the tools are not so separate and you are never going to use them separately, just make it one library with one CMakeLists.txt that links with all the libraries.