# Does cmake have something like target_link_options?

Tags: cmake

You can set the COMPILE_OPTIONS on an INTERFACE library (**foo**)
and those COMPILE_OPTIONS will also be used by the users of
**foo**.

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE foo_1)
target_compile_options(foo INTERFACE "-DSOME_DEFINE")
add_executable(exe exe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe foo)
```

Is it possible to do something similar for LINK_FLAGS ?

Comment: Can you share a particular use case?

Comment: @ruslo, sure. For example, a library that needs LD flag "--allow-multiple-definitions" or on windows /FORCE:MULTIPLE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a linker or compile flag in a CMake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets) there is no such property as `INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS` or something. Probably because `INTERFACE_*` properties used to describe how to use target (like avoiding violation of ODR rule or undefined references) and such options like `--allow-multiple-definitions` is not related to usage of a specific library (IMHO it's an indication of an error).

Anyway, for compiler like `gcc` you can use `target_link_libraries` to add linker flags too:

```
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE "-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition")
```

But I don't know how to do something like that for visual studio.

Comment: that worked. For windows* I expect that replacing "-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition" with "/FORCE:multiple".

    * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx

Comment: I think there's another use case for this. For example using LD:--undefined=symbol , or --allow-shlib-undefined.
I think it's not added to CMake since it's easier to have a compiler agnostic (defines) instead of mapping the linker options to INTERFACE_* properties ?

Comment: @ruslo: use `-` instead of `/` for cl.exe linker options, cl.exe accepts both and starting with `-` avoids the misinterpretation as library name

Comment: `target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE optimized -LTCG optimized -INCREMENTAL:NO)`  works with `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.6.4` and CMake 3.11

Answer (score 48):

CMake has a `target_link_options` starting from version [`3.13`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_options.html) that does *exactly* that.

```
target_link_options(<target> [BEFORE]
  <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]
  [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...] ...])
```

> [`target_link_options` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html)

Comment: Using 3.6.4111459 with AndroidStudio, I get: Unknown CMake command "target_link_options".

Comment: @Bram You need to upgrade the version to at least version 3.13. Check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471908/upgrade-cmake-version-installed-with-android-studio-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: As per documentation, this command cannot be used to add options for static library targets, since they do not use a linker. To add archiver or MSVC librarian flags, see the STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS target property.

Answer (score 15):

**Edit**: Modern CMake now provides `target_link_options()`, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53190881/3814202).

---

You could try something like this:

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE foo_1)
target_compile_options(foo INTERFACE "-DSOME_DEFINE")
add_executable(exe exe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe foo)

set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "My lib link flags")
set_target_properties(exe PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "My exe link flags")
```