# Upgrade CMake version installed with Android-Studio Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I recently installed Android Studio on Ubuntu 18.04 to do some native C++ development for Android. While compiling a project that required cmake 3.9 or higher (due to cmake dependencies) I found that the cmake version installed by Android Studio was only version 3.6. Is there a clean way to upgrade the cmake version installed with Android Studio via the SDK Manager?

I'm running Android Studio version 3.1.3 and Installed cmake from SDK Manager -> SDK tools.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the Official [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#vanilla_cmake),

The SDK Manager includes forked versions of CMake up to version **3.6.4**. If you want to use CMake version **3.7 or higher**, proceed as follows:

1. Update Android Studio to 3.0 or higher, and update the Android plugin for Gradle to 3.0.0 or higher.
2. [Download and install](https://cmake.org/download/) CMake 3.7 or higher from the official CMake website.
3. Specify the CMake version you want Gradle to use in your module's `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   android {
      externalNativeBuild {
          cmake {
              version "3.7.1"
          }
      }
   }
   ```
4. Either add the path to the CMake installation to your PATH environment variable or include it in your project's `local.properties` file, as `cmake.dir="path-to-cmake"`. If Gradle is unable to find the version of CMake you specified in your `build.gradle` file, you get a build error. If you set this property, Gradle no longer uses PATH to find CMake.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 13):

Also from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#vanilla_cmake):

> While not a best practice, you may specify the CMake version as the minimum version by adding a `+` to the end of the build.gradle entry, such as `3.10.2+`.

This will enable the *"or higher"* part of your question.

Comment: It's not on documentation anymore and this comment appears to be the only reference for this for CMake on Android Studio's Gradle plugin. But it still works!

Comment: Following up in Feb. 2023... `externalNativeBuild {cmake {version = '3.18.1+'}}` is working like a charm as well. Thanks @jpihl!

Answer (score 3):

`Preference -> System Settings -> Android SDK` then choose `SDK Tools` tab

Under that tab find `Cmake` section check the box which has higher version and uncheck the rest. then apply and re-sync project.

Comment: nope, it will use the ndk version anyway:  AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake: