# Studio build error: cannot find symbol method createDeviceProtectedStorageContext()

Tags: android

Not able to build my app in Studio using the below line of code :

```
        Context deviceContext = context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext();
```

Showing below error on build :

`error: cannot find symbol method createDeviceProtectedStorageContext()`

Using sdkVersions:  **minSdkVersion 24** **targetSdkVersion 29**

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.uvw"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29

        ndk {
            moduleName "libxyz_native"
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.7.1"
        }
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguardandroid.txt'),'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compileOnly project(':abc_studio_jar')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: can you show your app level gradle file ?

Comment: Edited the question with the gradle file.

Comment: Your Android Studio version ?

Comment: Android Studio version 3.5.3

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/51472416/9408181

Comment: Can you please tell me more as to why I should try this ?

Comment: because you use native library which didn't match current SDK version, kindly please upgrade or downgrade library version .