# Getting The command line is too long.ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed error while doing add_custom_command on android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I am trying to include all the .h files from a directory to another:

```
# copy out the lib binary... need to leave the static lib around to pass gradle check
set(libraries_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../libraries)
set(include_DIR ${libraries_DIR}/abc/include)

set_target_properties(abc
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        "${libraries_DIR}/abc/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}")

FILE(GLOB files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/a/b/c/d/*.h")

MESSAGE("FILE LIST IS: ${files}")

# copy out lib header file... to libraries/abc
#CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR points to abc for this CMakeLists.txt file
add_custom_command(TARGET abc POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${include_DIR})

FOREACH(file ${files})
    add_custom_command(TARGET abc POST_BUILD
            COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E
            copy "${file}"
            "${include_DIR}/"
            COMMENT "Copying abc headers : ${file}")
ENDFOREACH()
```

This is giving The command line is too long.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. error. Is there anybody who has an idea about it? Same code works fine for macOS. But I am trying it on windows. I have tried cleaning build and cxx folder but no luck

Comment: I am not sure, but probably Ninja generator combines all `POST_BUILD` events for a single target in to the single shell command. Why do you ever use `POST_BUILD` events instead of common `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` command flow? Build events are useful when you need to post-process executable/library file or take some other actions according to that **file**. In your case, the headers definitely do not depend on the executable/library created from them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, do you have any workaround for it?

Comment: As I said, you may use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` command flow (instead of `add_custom_command(TARGET)` which you are using now). Remember to create a target (via `add_custom_target`) which depends on all your OUTPUT files.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: @squareskittles, VERSION 3.10.2

Comment: This problem seems to be documented (and fixed) in the CMake issue [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/15612). This was around the timeframe that CMake 3.11 was released. Perhaps, using 3.11 or 3.12 or greater will resolve the problem?

Comment: @squareskittles, I am having highest version of cmake in android studio. Do I need to add it separately? Can you tell the steps?

Comment: You probably need to download and install it separately, then update your Android Studio config. A quick Google search yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471908/upgrade-cmake-version-installed-with-android-studio-ubuntu-18-04).