# How to add compile flags in cmake on windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, compiler-flags, ninja

I wrote a project using CMake (with ninja and Visual Studio 2017 C++ compiler), with two modules `lib_A` and `lib_B`

- `lib_B` depends one `lib_A`.
- Both `lib_B` and `lib_A` define `std::vector < size_t >`.

Finally, the compiler told me: `LNK2005 lib_A: std::vector < size_t > already defined in lib_B`

I searched answers, and they gave the solution to add link flag `/FORCE:MULTIPLE`, [page1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043458/does-cmake-have-something-like-target-link-options) and [page2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file).

I tried all these, but none of them work.

---

1. Use `target_link_libraries`

   - with `target_link_libraries(lib_B lib_A INTERFACE "/FORCE:MULTIPLE")`
   - compiler tells me `The INTERFACE, PUBLIC or PRIVATE option must appear as the second argument, just after the target name.`
   - with `target_link_libraries(lib_B INTERFACE "/FORCE:MULTIPLE" lib_A )`
   - compiler tells me `ninja: error: '/FORCE:MULTIPLE', needed by 'lib_B', missing and no known rule to make it`

---

2. Use `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`

   - with`set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "/FORCE:MULTIPLE")`
   - compile tells me `LINK : warning LNK4012: value “x64;/FORCE:MULTIPLE” is invalid, must be one of "ARM, EBC, HYBRID_X86_ARM64X64, or X86" omit this option"`

---

3. Use `set_target_properties`
   with CMake code

```
get_target_property(TEMP lib_B COMPILE_FLAGS)
if(TEMP STREQUAL "TEMP-NOTFOUND")
  SET(TEMP "") # Set to empty string
else()
  SET(TEMP "${TEMP} ") # A space to cleanly separate from existing content
endif()
# Append our values
SET(TEMP "${TEMP} /FORCE:MULTIPLE" )
set_target_properties(lib_B PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${TEMP} )
```

The compiler tells me `cl: command line error D8021 : invalid parameter "/FORCE:MULTIPLE"`

---

If I change `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` to `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition`, compiler tells me similar result.

Could anyone help me?
Does add link flag with any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) in CMake ≥ 3.13 or [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) with the `LINK_FLAGS` property before.

i.e. `target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/FORCE:MULTIPLE>)`

This also uses [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to only apply the flag for MSVC.

But it seems like both your libraries are shared (DLL), but you are statically linking the runtime to both. 
I don’t think that that’s a good idea.

Try either linking to the runtime dynamically for both libs if you want to dynamically link to them, or use the static runtime but build both libraries as static library too.

Comment: by the way, waht do you mean by `statically linking the runtime to both`? Does `target_link_libraries(lib_B lib_A)` linking statically? Then how to link dynamically ?

Comment: @Laine i may have misunderstood what the actual issue was. I assumed your getting multiple definitions was due to several conflicting standard libraries. Do you maybe instead have a variable with the same name in both libraries?

Comment: No, you didn't misunderstand me. I use `typedef` in `lib_A`, and refer the `typedef`ed class in `lib_B`, but msvc told me `LNK1169`, i.e., the `**` class already defined in `lib_A`. And what the most wierd is, two classes used the `typedef`ed class, but only one got the `LNK1169` error.

Comment: @Laine i tried to test if something like this not supposed to work, but your statements are still too little/inexact info to be able to tell if msvc actually erroneously instantiates something for a typedef here or if there are conflicting definitions from a c++ standard POV in your setup. You could elaborate on the types, variables and includes in question, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line worked for me:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /FORCE:MULTIPLE")
```

Comment: although it works, using those global flags is somewhat antiquated

Comment: @Darklighter: We are using these flags to globally set the same flags for all projects. But, I'll also consider `target_link_options` as an alternate. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Alepho the code doesn't work for me. I tried another way by explicit export with ```template class MyExports std::vector < size_t >```. Then the compile errors disappers currently.