# gcov not generating all gcda files

Tags: c++, cmake, gcov

I already tried a lot of solutions that i founded but none of then work. I'm working on a new code for a project, but this code was touched by a lot of master and doctor degrees that do not care on make it readeable. So there is really bunch of things that is not useful or even used.

Then i head about gcov and lcov, but after i generate .info file and load into lcov html, besides of all my files it just track the main file! Even knowing a lot of other functions and files were used!

(Really sorry for my bad english, im from Manaus, Amazonas - Brazil and not a good english speaker! But ive looked for this answer for like a month trying alot of things but got no luck at all)

My files look like:

```
    -src/
       -core/
         -Index.cpp/h
         -PostingList.cpp/h
         -PreProcessor.cpp/h
       -methods/
         ...
       -parser/
         ...
       -run/
         ...
       -structures/
         ...
       -utils/
         ...
```

I got a CMakeFile.txt in project source directory that look like this:

```
   cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4)
   project (queryProcessor)

   include("${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/globalVariables.cmake")

   include_directories(${INCLUDES})

   link_directories(${LIBS})

   if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
     cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
   endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

   add_subdirectory(src)

   add_executable(QueryProcessor src/run/queryProcessor.cpp)
   target_link_libraries (QueryProcessor libQueryProcessor rt -fprofile-arcs)

   add_definitions(-O2 )
```

and another on src directory that looks like this:

```
   aux_source_directory( utils UTILS )
   aux_source_directory( parser PARSER )
   aux_source_directory( methods METHODS )
   aux_source_directory( structures STRUCTURES )
   aux_source_directory( core CORE )
   aux_source_directory( . SRC )
   aux_source_directory( ../../libs-iw/indexer/include UTILS2 )

   add_library( libQueryProcessor ${UTILS} ${UTILS2} ${SRC} ${PARSER} ${METHODS} ${STRUCTURES} ${CORE})

   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--coverage")

   include ( ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/install.cmake )
```

Any help will be appreciated including suggestions for better CMakeFiles,
thanks in advance

Comment: Have libQueryProcessor object files actually been compiled with proper flags? Use `make clean; make VERBOSE=1` to switch to the verbose mode and carefully inspect compiler and linker invocation flags.

Comment: Also, it's wise to move all compilation flag manipulations _before_ defining a new target or adding a subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks @user3159253! Already move flag manipulations now and readed carefully the verbose output. The only difference from a file to another is when linking the CXX executable it has a -fprofile-arcs argument, Is this the one that in every cpp need to have?

Comment: @thomazandrade You should try [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com). It's in Portuguese (em Português). Your English isn't that bad, but I figured you might be more comfortable over there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for a delay.

You need to *compile* every source file in the program with proper options to use gcov. The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov) mentions `-fprofile-args -ftest-coverage`, but you might want to use other option related to profiling as well.

So you need to *append* those flags as suggested in [How to add linker or compile flag in cmake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file) before all target definitions (i.e. somewhere near the beginning of the main `CMakeLists.txt`) You may want to add an CMake option to control these flags at once:

```
option(USE_GCOV "Create a GCov-enabled build." OFF)
...
if (USE_GCOV)
  set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
  set(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lgcov")
endif()
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
...
add_subdirectory(...)
add_library(....)
add_executable(....)
```

Comment: Really thank you!! Now it works like a charm, the only problem is that it generate .gcda files in a lot of differents folders, but i will look now for a solution! Thanks again!! Have a great week

Comment: Depending on your needs there could be various solutions. You may write a shell script to -rule- collect them all, or you may try to re-structure where your object files get created. You just need to formulate your needs more precisely and ask proper questions ;)