# Linker error with CMake

Tags: sqlite, cmake

I'm using JetBrains CLion for pure C (C ANSI) development, I know it's target is C++, but my company works only with C and
CLion uses only CMake as build system.

My system is a Debian Jessie system and sqlite3 and libsqlite3-dev are installed.

I'm trying to build a simple sqlite3 project like this:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    sqlite3 *sqlConnection;
    int ret;
    ret = sqlite3_open("database/path.db, &sqlConnection);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Ups ... can't open %d", ret);
    }
    do_some_queries(sqlConnection);
    return 0;
}
```

The automatic generated CMakeLists.txt is the follwing.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)


project(Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp )
add_executable(Project ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When build, either through Clion, either through command line, I get linker errors:

```
...
undefined reference to `sqlite3_prepare_v2'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_int'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
...
```

I know I must point out to CMake where sqlite3 is, but I can't find a way of doing this.

"find_package" and "find_library" may do it, but I can't find how.

I've also found [this Cmake file](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake), but could not used successfully.

So, how do I integrate sqlite3 with Cmake ?

Comment: Add `sqlite3.c` to the sources.

Comment: @CL. you say download sqlite3 source code and compile it together with the project ? I've tried it and got other linker errors (threading and etc), moreover, don't like duplicating sources around the system. Will try tough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add linker or compile flag in cmake file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the path to sqlite header file to your include path. Then link the sqlite library using `target_link_libraries`:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: this libsqlite3-dev already put the sqlite3.h on the gcc path, same for -lsqlite3 option, so how I send the "-lsqlite3" option for the underlaying GCC on Cmake ?

Comment: You did not understand the answer, right? sqlite3 should be added via target_link_libraries.

Comment: So should just `target_link_libraries(sqlite3)` work?? @usr1234567 @Cristiano

Answer (score -1):

I've founded a workaround, but it's not the correct way of doing.

Since on Debian the "gcc main.c -lsqlite3" works (with libsqlite3-dev installed), passing the -lsqlite3 flag to the linker do the trick.

so I've changed

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

to

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lsqlite3")
```

And it worked.

Comment: -l is a linker flag, your non-solution just works by chance. Have a closer look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file