# Get free space left on target from arm-none-eabi-size

Tags: arduino, arm, size, binutils

I want to calculate space left on my embedded target.

The Arduino IDE shows this in the output window:

```
Sketch uses 9544 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
```

`avr-size` has `-C` option that shows "xx% left":

```
$ avr-size -C --mcu=atmega32u4 build/myproject.hex
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega32u4

Program:    8392 bytes (25.6% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:       2196 bytes (85.8% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)
```

However, I'm actually writing a CMake file to develop code for an Arduino board with an Arm Cortex M0 CPU, so I use `arm-none-eabi-size`, which shows the code size like this:

```
[100%] Built target hex
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   8184     208    1988   10380    288c build/myproject
[100%] Built target size
*** Finished ***
```

Is there a way to calculate the program and data space left on the device? Or do I need to regex the output and calculate percent of a hard-coded value?

Comment: how deep does your stack get worst case?  Or are you talking flash only?

Comment: For now, I mostly care about flash. I was hoping there is a hidden option like with `avr-size`, an alternative `arm-none-eabi-size` that can do the calculation, or a program that runs `arm-none-eabi-size` and parses its output...

Comment: avr-whatever-objcopy -O binary myprog.elf myprog.bin  and see how big the .bin file is.    readelf and others should also have similar information.

Comment: and it looks like the tools are already telling you this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using arm-none-eabi toolchain, you can add linker option `-Wl,--print-memory-usage` which prints RAM and Flash usage in percentage. Output looks like this:

```
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
             RAM:        8968 B        20 KB     43.79%
           FLASH:       34604 B       128 KB     26.40%
```

I am using make file generated by CubeMX, to enable this print I added the option at the end of LDFLAGS line. For CMake this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file) might be useful.