# Pass option to compiler but not to the linker in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, linker, flags

With cmake one can pass compiler options with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS` to the linker.

But as far as I can see `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are passed to the linker as well.

**Is there a way to pass options to the compiler but not to the linker?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a linker or compile flag in a CMake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file). This [specific response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28773403/3987854) shows how you *should* be passing compile/link options using CMake (i.e. not using `CMAKE_*_FLAGS`, as this is antiquated and discouraged).

Answer (score 0):

Use **target_compile_options** to add compiler options to a specific target

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html

Use **target_link_options** to add linker options to a specific target

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html

Modern cmake projects should avoid using CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS/CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS unless you really know what you are doing.