# how to overwrite/append CMAKE_C_CFLAG

Tags: cmake, cmake-language, cmakelists-options

cmake version : 3.18.5 MinGW Makefiles
Host : windows
target : ppc
compiler : windriver

I want to create two different executables with different flags.
for execample i want to create one executable with flag(-tPPCE) and another with flag(-tPPCEV), These flags define the type of hardware.
If i try to set this value in their respective CMakelists.txt with

```
    set_target_properties(app1 PROPERTIES CMAKE_C_FLAGS -tPPCE)
    set_target_properties(app2 PROPERTIES CMAKE_C_FLAGS -tPPCEV)
```

it is not working.

It is working only if i set this value in the toolchain file where i have set all other flags.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28773403/3440745) for the duplicate question describes how to add compiler flags for a single target. It uses `target_compile_options` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `target_compile_options` method:

```
target_compile_options(app1 PRIVATE "-tPPCE")
target_compile_options(app2 PRIVATE "-tPPCEV")
```

Comment: ya, it is working now.. thanks