# How to use Set directory properties

Tags: cmake

I used Set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "--saferc=none") to mask misra check in directory, but I got Warning:
Ccv850:Warning:option "-D--saferc=none" ignored due to invalid argument. Expected name or name=string.

Comment: The property [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) contains **macro definitions**, which will be available in C/C++ code. For pass general **options** to the compiler you can use e.g. command [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html). See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file) and its answers for more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**You should basically never use directory properties, ever.**

For whichever *targets* cannot compile without the flag, you can add it like so:

```
target_compile_options(
  my_target
  PRIVATE 
  "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GHS>:--saferc=none>"
  "$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:GHS>:--saferc=none>"
)
```

My understanding is that `--saferc=none` is a Green Hills flag, hence the check for `$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GHS>`. If you are only using one of C or C++, you can delete the flag for the other language.

Comment: Thanks Alex,  Actually i want to mask misra check for some file at folder level. So is there any way to do so?