# G++ Parameters to Cmakelist

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, cmakelists-options

I am trying to build my Project using cmake. With 3rd Party headerfiles and libarys. The headers are in `/usr/local/include/` and the libary in `/usr/local/lib/`. And I think the compiler finds the files because I get no error on the includes but when I try to compile it it doesn´t find the functions I´m calling.

```
/mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `ola::InitLogging(ola::log_level, ola::log_output)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `ola::DmxBuffer::DmxBuffer()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `ola::DmxBuffer::Blackout()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `ola::client::StreamingClient::StreamingClient(ola::client::StreamingClient::Options const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `ola::client::StreamingClient::Setup()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `ola::DmxBuffer::SetChannel(unsigned int, unsigned char)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `ola::client::StreamingClient::SendDmx(unsigned int, ola::DmxBuffer const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `ola::client::StreamingClient::~StreamingClient()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `ola::DmxBuffer::~DmxBuffer()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `ola::client::StreamingClient::~StreamingClient()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/Max/CLionProjects/Lightning_Controller/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `ola::DmxBuffer::~DmxBuffer()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I compile it with G++ and this parameters `g++ main.cpp -lola -lolacommon -lprotobuf` it works.

I tried to use the Option Mentioned in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file) but it didn´t change anything.

My Question is how do i translate this from g++ to cmake ?

Comment: You have the issue in your CMakeLists.txt but you don't show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to have more information about what you are doing, but this is what I have for you.

The compiler can't find the implementation for the functions you're calling. It finds the headers, but it doesn't link the library with the actual implementations. With `CMake`, specify the libraries to link.

I don't know what version of C++ you are on, so change it accordingly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Lightning_Controller)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(/usr/local/include/)

add_executable(Lightning_Controller main.cpp)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib/)

target_link_libraries(Lightning_Controller ola olacommon protobuf)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The missing part was the `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: I prefer the use of `target_include_directories` and `target_link_directories` to the commands applying to any target defined afterwards; It's just easier to reason about the targets it affects, if the choice is made on a per-target basis (and possibly "inherited" by linking targets). For the same reason I prefer the use of `target_compile_features(Ligntning_Controller PRIVATE cxx_std_14)` to `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`