# How to get the code coverage in gtest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am tying to do unit test using google test. But the gtest doesnt display the code coverage in the console. How can I get the code coverage of my unit test by using gtest?

Comment: To get the code coverage of your unit test you should use appropriate tool which depends what OS/compiler/environment you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google-test: code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359344/google-test-code-coverage)