# How to Generate code coverage report using Gtest on Windows by using Gcov and Lcov

Tags: c++, googletest, spring-test, gcov, lcov

I am using gtest for testing my code in C++ with Vs code,  I am able to generate test report, but I could not genetare gtest code coverage report, I installed gcov lcov. I would like to know that, is there any way to find out the code coverage gtest or not? as I have googled a lot, but I could not find any possible way to get the code coverage result by using Gcov and Lcov in Windows environment. If there is any possibility, please let me know.

Thank You.

I am expecting Gtest code coverage report by using Gcov and Lcov in HTML format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljA7v.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google-test: code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359344/google-test-code-coverage)